# How to input array in TKinter Entry?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

How to enter array elements into TKinter Entry?
For the console it is like this:

```
lst1 = []
lst2 = []

lst1 = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the list items : ").split()]

lst2 = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the list items : ").split()]

print(lst1)
print(lst2)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Entre array automatically?

Comment: Have you looked at any `tkinter` tutorials? Do you know how to make a simple tkinter window/add widgets to that window? I guess you know that you will need a bunch of `tkinter.Entry`s, that are created dynamically? Are there any constraints on the size of the user's input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example:

```
import tkinter as tk
lst1 = []
lst2 = []

def enterItems():
    items1 = entry1.get()
    items2 = entry2.get()
    lst1 = [int(item) for item in items1.split()]
    lst2 = [int(item) for item in items2.split()]
    entry1.destroy()
    entry2.destroy()
    button.destroy()
    displayText = tk.Text(root)
    displayText.grid()
    displayText.insert('1.0','List 1:\n'+str(lst1)+'\n\nList 2:\n'+str(lst2))


if __name__== "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, text = 'enter array 1 here')
    entry1.grid()
    entry2 = tk.Entry(root, text = 'enter array 2 here')
    entry2.grid()
    button = tk.Button(root, text = 'submit', command = enterItems)
    button.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nested functions are considered bad practise most of the time. Also you never call `root.mainloop()` (you missed the brackets).

Comment: Just a note: Wouldn't it be better to destroy the 2 entries and button instead of destroying the window and creating a new one? Apart from that, great answer

Comment: @TheLizzard I think that it would be better as less information will need to be stored. (I edited the answer again to do this; thanks again for the input!)